# Wrapping an IntPtr in a Struct for safer Interop

Tags: c#, pointers, type-safety, lua

Consider the following C#/C interop scenario:

```
public static extern IntPtr lua_newstate();
public static extern void lua_close(IntPtr state);

IntPtr luaState = lua_newstate();
// use lua ...
lua_close(luaState)
```

Obviously this works well enough, however there's a fringe possibility that an `IntPtr` *not* pointing to a lua state could be passed to `lua_close`, since it accepts *any* `IntPtr`.

I realized that it's possible to use the behavior of struct marshaling to make this interop a bit more type-safe

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct LuaState
{
    public readonly IntPtr Pointer;
}

public static extern LuaState lua_newstate();
public static extern void lua_close(LuaState state);

LuaState luaState = lua_newstate();
// use lua ...
lua_close(luaState)
```

Since `LuaState` contains only an `IntPtr`, the marshaler happily converts the native pointer returned by `lua_newstate` to an instance of `LuaState`, and will also quite happily convert a `LuaState` struct to a native pointer when passed back to a native function.

This essentially creates a typed pointer. There is a cost associated with passing `LuaState` though the Marshaling system instead of passing `IntPtr` directly to the native side, but in testing the cost appears to be negligible.

**Questions:** Does using `LuaState` to create a typed wrapper for `IntPtr` in this way raise any red flags? Has anyone done something similar and run into issues?

Comment: Perhaps consider SafeAccessTokenHandle (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safeaccesstokenhandle.aspx) ?

Answer (score 5):

I think, I would experiment with a safe or smart pointer approach in a way like this:

```
public sealed class LuaHandle : IDisposable
{
  private static extern IntPtr lua_newstate();
  private static extern void lua_close(IntPtr state);

  private IntPtr m_handle = IntPtr.Zero;

  public LuaHandle()
  {
    m_handle = lua_newstate();
  }

  public IntPtr Handle => m_handle;


  public void Dispose()
  {
    if (m_handle != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
      lua_close(m_handle);
    }

    m_handle = IntPtr.Zero;
  }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
  using (LuaHandle luaHandle = new LuaHandle())
  {
    // do something with luaHandle.Handle
  }
```

In this way you - as a client of LuaHandle - don't have to deal with the extern api's at all and no invalid IntPtr can be past as argument to `lua_close()`

Comment: Hadn't considered a wrapper like this. Thanks!

Comment: Typo at `public selaed`?